# How to permanently save (and load) Gnome's per-display configuration on Wayland?

Tags: gnome, wayland, display-settings

Gnome (44.5) resets any display back to the default configuration when the said device is disabled (in the Gnome settings → displays), resulting in 100% scale and 60.00 Hz refresh rate, for a 120 Hz panel (and presumably above, I don't own such screen). 4K displays and beyond are generally used at ≥200% scaling.

I have to keep toggling the state of my TV since I'm suffering from [the bug which causes application windows to appear on the secondary screen](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/729). The windows can and are also moved to the non-primary display when its screen is turned off and the mouse cursor appears not to be tied to the main monitor in multi-monitor setups (i.e. more than one display enabled, but not necessarily on at all times). I'm uncertain if mixed use (LCD panel for work, OLED for entertainment) is viable on this desktop environment without getting another dedicated computer.